# Error in multiple plotting in R using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

Suppose you have two data frames with equal column names, but different values. You now want to make a scatterplot on the different values in the corresponding columns in the two data frames.

```
for ( i in 1:length(a) {
    pdf("test.pdf")
    par(mfrow = c(5,3))
    plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[i]], a[, colnames(a)[i]])
    dev.off()
}
```

This does not work, you only get one plot of the 13 plots.

Doing it manually work, IF YOU WAIT SOME SECONDS BETWEEN EACH PLOT.

```
par(mfrow = c(5,3))
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[1]], a[, colnames(a)[1]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[2]], a[, colnames(a)[1]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[2]], a[, colnames(a)[3]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[3]], a[, colnames(a)[3]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[2]], a[, colnames(a)[2]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[4]], a[, colnames(a)[4]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[5]], a[, colnames(a)[5]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[6]], a[, colnames(a)[6]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[7]], a[, colnames(a)[7]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[8]], a[, colnames(a)[8]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[9]], a[, colnames(a)[9]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[10]], a[, colnames(a)[10]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[11]], a[, colnames(a)[11]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[12]], a[, colnames(a)[12]])
plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[13]], a[, colnames(a)[13]])
```

Why on earth does this happened?

You cannot run all at once, you have to wait some seconds, is this why the for loop don't work?

Comment: Your loop overwrites the same PDF 13 times. Put `i` in the filename using `paste` or some such, to get 13 differently-named files.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Misstanke in the length(a) argument. And also, it works if I put the par() outside the loop. par(mfrow = c(5,3))

for ( i in 1:length(colnames(a))) {
        plot(WAT_cpm[, colnames(a)[i]], a[, colnames(a)[i]])
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put `pdf("test.pdf")` and `dev.off()`outside the loop. Result : 1 file and 1page by plot.